# how do i process Flux<Object> returned by webflux at client side in plain java code

Tags: web-services, java-8, spring-webflux

I have written a webservice using spring webflux and reactive mongodb connectors, but my client side could be non spring based client. 
So, how do I write a plain java code to consume flex at client side?

ServerSide code:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/findAll")
    public Flux<Security> findAll() {
        Flux<Security> flux = service.findAll();
        return flux;
    }
```

Client side code:

```
 public static void sendRequest() {
            try {

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/findAll/");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/stream+json");

                if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    // url = new URL("http://localhost:8182/status/");

                    String json = "";
                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())))) {
                        json = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
                    }

                    conn.disconnect();
                    System.out.println("size of each Security: " + json.length());

                    ArrayList<Security> list = getListOfsecurities(json);
                    System.out.println(list.get(0).getIsin());

                }
            }
```

The above client side gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. It's an asynchronous response.At least you have to use Java 5 Futures to invoke asynchronous response.

Comment: but isn'tt webflux is a rest api? so if it is rest then it should send back a json over http? how would a non java app use my webservice if webflux is not a rest api?